# Render part of the template in Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

What is the proper way how to implement the following functionality:

The (Flask) web application view consists of several DIVs that contain some html content (ie, lists of items pulled from database). Once the view is downloaded to the browser, the content of the DIVs will be updated individually, depending on the user actions, by help of AJAX requests.

I know there are macros feature in the Jinja2 template engine that is part of the Flask micro framework. Perhaps there is a way how to render only certain macro, then I could use it to serve the partial content.

But then again, perhaps that is not the right way to achieve this functionality, and there is more "right" way.

Comment: Normally, you would pull down JSON data and then render into HTML locally in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.get_template_attribute) actually has an example that does exactly what you describe:

Template:

```
{% macro hello(name) %}Hello {{ name }}!{% endmacro %}
```

View:

```
hello = get_template_attribute('_cider.html', 'hello')
return hello('World')
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works, with just one caveat: if my template contains reference to the request object, then retrieving the template attribute is not possible. This happens even if the required macro does not contain any references to global objects. I am not sure how to circumvent that.

Comment: Yes, the entire template must compile successfully. You should probably move your macro into a separate template file, which you can then both import into your other templates _and_ access in views via `get_template_attribute`.